# android studio - не запускается эмулятор

Tags: linux, android-studio, эмулятор, archlinux

Хотел изучить разработку под android. Создал тестовый проект, однако, эмулятор не запускается. Запускаю android-studio через терминал. Выводит следующее:

```
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@4d76f3f8 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/admin/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/tmp/jna6610982474153361655.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/admin/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/tmp/jna6610982474153361655.tmp
[  22346]   WARN - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - NDK support for project 'MyApp' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
[ 337579]   WARN - run.EmulatorConnectionListener - Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

А в консоли android-studio:

```
 Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

Разницы нет, что ставить через yaourt или самому. Также пробовал удалять каталоги: ~/.android и ~/.AndroidStudio2.3 - не помогло. Раньше писало, что не находит файл ~/.android/repositories.cfg. В инете сказано, что его надо создать самому. Создал. Warning пропал. Но какой толк от этого пустого файла? Еще выводило, что найдена библиотека libnotify.so.4. Переустановил libnotify, пропало предупреждение.

Система Archlinux

Comment: Настройки все выполнили ? Графический рендеринг включили для ПО ? Какие графические драйвера используете в арче ?

Comment: 1) выполнил, 2) как включить? 3) драйвер xf86-video-ati

Comment: Как влючить я не знаю, т.к. не занимаюсь разработкой в android studio. Решение на англоязычном стаке:
**The solution for me was setting the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware.**
Не могу сказать про поддержку AMD для андроид студии в арче.

Comment: а, это я включал, не помогало